# RingCentral Voice Call in ASP.NET MVC 4.6.2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, call, ringcentral

I am trying to make voice call on ringCentral in my ASP.NET MVC 4.6.2. I used code from ringCentral documentation regarding C#. But When I try to make a call. It shows "The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed" on line: "var resp = await restClient.Restapi().Account().Extension().RingOut().Post(parameters);"

Note: I am trying to make a call from ringCentral Sandbox phone number to my personal phone number in Pakistan. The Code is attached below:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task Call_From_RingCentral()
{
    restClient = new RestClient(
    "65ty", //client id
    "12gh", //client secret
    "https://platform.devtest.ringcentral.com"); //server url
    await restClient.Authorize("JWT");
    await call_ringout();
  }

  static private async Task call_ringout()
  {
    var parameters = new MakeRingOutRequest();
    parameters.from = new MakeRingOutCallerInfoRequestFrom
    {
        phoneNumber = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("+13232......")
    };
    parameters.to = new MakeRingOutCallerInfoRequestTo
    {
        phoneNumber = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("+92300067.....")
    };
    parameters.playPrompt = false;

    var resp = await 
     restClient.Restapi().Account().Extension().RingOut().Post(parameters);
     Console.WriteLine("Call Placed. Call status" + resp.status.callStatus);
   }
```

Comment: the authentication method may of changed on the Server.  Many APP are switching from Windows Credentials to OAUTH2 because OAUTH2 will work with Windows, Linux, and Mac.  When was the last time you used the code?  How old is the code you are using (check date of last update).  What authentication method is the server using?

Comment: I used that code yesterday. I got that code from the official doc yesterday. According to official doc, it is using JWT so I am using JWT as well. Everything is same as mentioned in official doc.

Comment: Did the code work when you used it yesterday?  Did you remove any version of Net from your machine since yesterday?  You may of may some changes from yesterday that is now giving a different error.  You are using old code from Net 4.6.2.  If HTTPS (secure using TLS), not all encryption methods worked properly.  Not until Net 4.7.1 TLS was done in OS instead of in Net.  Also server was probably using Windows Credentials in Net 4.6.2 and if server is using different credentials method the code will fail.  The error message is probably a timeout exception that connection never completed.

Comment: It wasn't working fine previously as well. However I tried on ringCentral api website as well, getting this response but still not getting any call: HTTP/1.1 200 OK

{
  "uri" : "https://platform.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/1133926004/extension/1133926004/ring-out/Y3MxNzE4NDI4NDkyODg0NDM5MDJAMTAuNjIuMjkuMzM",
  "id" : "Y3MxNzE4NDI4NDkyODg0NDM5MDJAMTAuNjIuMjkuMzM",
  "status" : {
    "callStatus" : "InProgress",
    "callerStatus" : "InProgress",
    "calleeStatus" : "InProgress"
    }
}

Comment: I think your code is good.  You are getting a 200 OK which indicates the server got you request and properly running the request.  Looks like the server is a gateway that sends the message over a telephone network and the telephone network is not completing the phone call (probably a SMS text message).  Try using a smart phone that will accept a SMS text message and see if that works.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried but getting "destinationBlocked" response: {
  "uri": "https://platform.devtest.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/815628005/extension/815628005/ring-out/s-a1d1479198aacz18a5fcb7616z8f3200000",
  "id": "s-a1d1479198aacz18a5fcb7616z8f3200000",
  "status": {
    "callStatus": "Success",
    "callerStatus": "Finished",
    "calleeStatus": "DestinationBlocked"
  }
}

Comment: It is in the body of the response which is the content.  You have to get the content and then use a json deserializer to get the properties.

Comment: Unfortunately sandbox phone numbers do not allow for calling international numbers, which is why you're likely getting the destination blocked result.  You can use a US/ CA number, or In the sandbox Service Web portal you can add another number and try calling that number instead.  Hope that helps!